# SQL Dynamic Pivot with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

| RABATTNR | MENGE | PREIS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222890 | 0.010 | 5.35 |
| 222890 | 101.000 | 3.85 |
| 222890 | 500.000 | 3.65 |

and I'd like to have the following result:

| RABATTNR | MENGE1 | PREIS1 | MENGE2 | PREIS2 | MENGE3 | PREIS3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222890 | 0.010 | 5.35 | 101.000 | 3.85 | 500.000 | 3.65 |

How could I achieve that?

Appreciate your help.

Thank you all.

i tried pivoting and unpivoting but the values in MENGE are becoming the headers for the new table and the values in the PREIS are the corresponding value

| RABATTNR | 0.010 | 101.000 | 500.000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222890 | 5.35 | 3.85 | 3.65 |

Comment: how many rows can you have per each RABATTNR? is it fix number or can change for different groups?

Comment: Tables in SQL, the language, aren't spreadsheets. You can't have arbitrary columns in a query result. That's why you need to specify the actual values you want to pivot on in the PIVOT clause. If you want to *transpose* the results, or create a jagged table, it's a lot easier to do this on the client. In SQL you'll have to count the possible "groups" and then construct a dynamic SQL query with one (or two) columns per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (copy paste friendly) alternative to @Luis LL's solution:

```sql
select rabattnr
,   max(case when x.sort = 1 then menge end) as menge1
,   max(case when x.sort = 1 then preis end) as preis1
,   max(case when x.sort = 2 then menge end) as menge2
,   max(case when x.sort = 2 then preis end) as preis2
,   max(case when x.sort = 3 then menge end) as menge3
,   max(case when x.sort = 3 then preis end) as preis3

from 
(
    select *
    ,   row_number() over(partition by rabattnr order by menge, preis) as sort
    FROM    (
            VALUES  (222890, 0.010, 5.35)
            ,   (222890, 101.000, 3.85)
            ,   (222890, 500.000, 3.65)
        ) t (RABATTNR,MENGE,PREIS)
    ) x
group by RABATTNR
```

I create a sort column which controls the order on which columns appear, then pivot each value by the standard MAX CASE WHEN solution, which creates one row per rabattnr with the correct values.
This query is easy to adapt in case you have more than 3 "rows".

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you a lot. Is there a way to make this dynamic in case I have (n) number of rows? thanks again!

Comment: Not without building your query dynamically. You'll have to count the most number of occuring RABATTNR, and then build the same number of MAX(CASE WHEN...)) rows. if you need dynamic pivot, sql is usually not the right tool, since it wants to know the number of columns ahead of time

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    RABATTNR INT,
    MENGE DECIMAL (10, 3),
    PREIS DECIMAL (10, 3)
)
INSERT INTO MyTable(RABATTNR, MENGE, PREIS)
VALUES 
(222890, 0.010, 5.35  ),
(222890, 101.000, 3.85),
(222890, 500.000, 3.65)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RABATTNR ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT cte1.RABATTNR, cte1.MENGE, cte1.PREIS PREIS1, cte2.MENGE MENGE2, cte2.PREIS PREIS2, cte3.MENGE MENGE3, cte3.PREIS PREIS3
FROM cte cte1 
INNER JOIN cte cte2 on cte1.RABATTNR = cte2.RABATTNR 
INNER JOIN cte cte3 on cte1.RABATTNR = cte3.RABATTNR
WHERE cte1.rn = 1 and cte2.rn = 2 and cte3.rn = 3
```