# SQL Server transpose from rows to columns (pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to use pivot function in sqlserver to make the transpose happen.

Here is the existed table:

| id | account | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | 2023/1/2 |
| 123 | def | 2023/2/1 |
| 123 | fsd | 2023/2/22 |
| 456 | ioj | 2023/2/1 |
| 456 | dju | 2023/2/10 |

Ideally, after the transpose, the output will look like below (only transpose maximum 3 records to the column):

| id | account1 | time1 | account2 | time2 | account3 | time3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | 2023/1/2 | def | 2023/2/1 | fsd | 2023/2/22 |
| 456 | ioj | 2023/2/1 | dju | 2023/2/10 |  |  |

I'm aware that using an inner join can make this happen, but wonder how I can achieve this by using "pivot" in sql server? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it depends... what happens if id 789 has 4 times?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `pivot` function? What exactly are you having trouble with? Show us your attempt!

Comment: @Stuckat1337, the universe as we know it will end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Dynamic Pivot with a twist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674598/sql-dynamic-pivot-with-a-twist)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit trickier cause you have multiple columns and levels.
What you could do is:

```sql
;with t AS (
    select *
    from (
        VALUES  (123, N'abc', N'2023/1/2')
        ,   (123, N'def', N'2023/2/1')
        ,   (123, N'fsd', N'2023/2/22')
        ,   (456, N'ioj', N'2023/2/1')
        ,   (456, N'dju', N'2023/2/10')
    ) t (id,account,time)
)
select id
,   MAX(CASE WHEN sort = 1 THEN account END) AS account1
,   MAX(CASE WHEN sort = 1 THEN time END) AS time1
,   MAX(CASE WHEN sort = 2 THEN account END) AS account2
,   MAX(CASE WHEN sort = 2 THEN time END) AS time2
,   MAX(CASE WHEN sort = 3 THEN account END) AS account3
,   MAX(CASE WHEN sort = 3 THEN time END) AS time3
from (
    select row_number() over(partition by id order by account, time) AS sort
    ,   *
    FROM    t
  ) x
group by id
```

You create a sort column which allows you to place each field in correct column "slot", then you do a MAX CASE WHEN to get the value you need.